# How to check whether a link is clickable in Playwright?

Tags: playwright

Consider the following screenshot:

[modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5iZ1.png)

Here, only buttons `I accept` and `More options` are clickable. The modal background prevents any clicks to the navigation links. Is it possible to use Playwright to select only links that are in current viewport and that would receive a click event should one occur within their bounding box?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I am also looking for this solution. Have u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of playwright's [actionability checks](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability) to narrow down links / buttons to only those that are clickable. Start with [locators](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-locator) to select all  tags (or buttons or something else depending what you're looking for). Iterate through the locators you get and run the checks you want on each

```python
locators = page.locator(selector)
locator_count = await locators.count()
for index in range(0, locator_count):
    locator = locators.nth(index)
    if await locator.is_visible() and await locator.is_enabled():
        # do your action
        ...
```

Edit:
Reading more and it looks like you can actually do those actionability checks using the [`trial` option with click.](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-click)
`page.click(selector, trial=True)`

Thats the look before you leap method. Playwright also [does these checks](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability#receives-events:%7E:text=for%20each%20action%3A-,Action,-Attached) before each click and other events, so if you're just looking to perform an action on a valid element, you can just `try` a click and handle the error if it's [not actionable](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-click). Like so:

```python
locators = page.locator(selector)
locator_count = await locators.count()
for index in range(0, locator_count):
    locator = locators.nth(index)
    try:
        await locator.click()
    except TimeoutError:
        # handle error. likely just skip this locator
        continue
```